# What is the time complexity of new and delete for primitive VS user-defined data types?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

From what I gathered, it depends on the implementation of the constructors and destructors for user-defined data types.

I was wondering if there is set time complexity / any guarantees for primitive data types allocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no such guarantee. Lacking constructors, the time complexity is entirely due to the underlying `operator new` which has to find free heap storage.

Note that some `operator new` call is also needed for classes, but this could be either the global `::operator new` or a class member. In both cases, it too needs to find free heap storage.